# Mote E 2nd Gen keypad not opening

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g2

My Moto E 2nd Gen (Lollipop) mobile keypad is not opening when I try to type a message or try to chat or search contacts. Google Voice opens "Tap to speak", which is not working either. "Language & Input setting" is not opening and shows "Unfortunately, setting has stopped".

I have cleared cache memories and restarted my mobile. I do not want to factory reset it.  What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Remove some unwanted apps and check. It might be that the phone does not have enough memory to perform the action.

This is not a sureshot solution, but if u do not wish to factory reset then you should try this.

Also, there are a number of apps which boost your phone memory. I prefer to use 360 Security.

You may try that!!

Comment: How does an app boost phone memory if its stock like most Motorola phones?

Answer (score 0):

I have this exact phone my guess is that you ran out of memory.  Try uninstalling the highest data usage applications.  Go under settings->storage->apps->running.

Also this is a side recommendation but convert as many apps to web apps as possible http://appsco.pe is a good site for web apps.